# How to get all Types using LINQ in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this code

```
 viewModel.Messages = repository.GetAllMessages().OrderBy(x => x.MessageText);
```

with this I am getting 75 messges and i am displaying all the Messages in the Grid with two columns

MessageText and MessageType

But I need to write a Linq Query to get all my Distinct MessageTypes from Messages?

Can any body help me out?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
repository.GetAllMessages().Select(m => m.MessageType).Distinct();
```